# Plots & complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm learning Complex Numbers by myself. I've already understood basics concepts, but now I have problems with plots/graphs.

For example, I don't know, how to plot:
(1) $|z-1|+|z+1|=4$

(2) $|z+1| - \Im z \leq 1$

(3) $\Re\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right) = 1$

($z \in \mathbb{C}$)

These examples are from some problem set I'm learning from (it's for first year college students)

I would really appreciate your help. I don't want to get answers for these particular problems. I want to **understand**, how can I plot similar *things*.

Comment: Take z=x+iy and redice the equations in complex variables to an equation in $x,y\in\mathcal{R}$ Notice that all the operations in your question return real arguments (Re, modulus, Im, etc)

Answer (score 7):

some of them are easier to view in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but some can be thought about directly.  for instance 1) is the locus of points $z$ in the plane the sum of whose distances from the points 1 and -1 (i.e. (1,0) and (-1,0)) is 4.  this is a description of an ellipse (you may recall).

Answer (score 3):

To graph these equations, I would just write out $z = x + iy$, and then use a standard graphing device, recognizing that we can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.  For instance, for the first equation, you could write:

$$
|x+iy - 1| + |x + iy + 1| = 4 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} = 4,
$$

and then plot the equation as usual.

Comment: Shouldn't there be square roots involved with your norm formula?

Comment: Why, yes there should be.  I apologize for not being sufficiently careful.